# CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: ['org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType' <-> byte]

Tags: java, cassandra

Seeing a weird issue, when query below table using Java data mapper: "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: ['org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType' <-> byte]
"

Should CQL tinyint be mapped to byte in Java driver automatically? What is ByteType?

```
CREATE TABLE abc.test (
  cityID int,
  planUUID UUID,
  versionID TIMEUUID,     
  status tinyint,
  PRIMARY KEY (cityID, planUUID, versionID)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (planUUID DESC, versionID DESC);

@Data
@Table(keyspace = "abc", name = "test")
public class TestSet {
  @PartitionKey private int cityID;

  @ClusteringColumn @NonNull private UUID planUUID;

  @ClusteringColumn(1)
  private UUID versionID;

  private byte status;
}
```

Comment: Failure is from unit test using cassandra-unit

Comment: what version of the driver is used?

Comment: ByteType was introduced after 3.0 http://javadox.com/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/3.0.0/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/ByteType.html

Comment: Java driver 3.7.1

Comment: Cassandra-unit 3.5.0.1